# Getting error when trying to include wkhtmltopdf in WordPress custom php file

Tags: php, wordpress, wkhtmltopdf

how to fix this error that I get when trying to include phpwkhtmltopdf in custom file in WordPress:

PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'mikehaertl\wkhtmlto\Pdf' not found in /wp-content/themes/default/custom/custom.php:4

and this is my PHP code:

```
include_once(get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/topdf/Pdf.php");
use mikehaertl\wkhtmlto\Pdf;
$pdf = new pdf();
var_dump($pdf);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong function to get the path to your phpwkhtmltopdf library.

From [the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri):

> Retrieve stylesheet directory URI for the current theme/child theme.
>
> (...)
>
> **If you want to include a local file in PHP, use [get_stylesheet_directory()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory) instead.**

(emphasis mine.)